# How to use a local DNS server with dd-wrt, and *not* use DNSMasq

Tags: dns, dd-wrt

I have a DNS server running on a Windows Server machine that resolves some local domain names into local IP addresses.

I simply want to use the Windows DNS server.  I do not want to use Dnsmasq.  I don't want to maintain new domains through the router.

I did the following to attempt to achieve what I'm looking for:

1. I set a static IP for the local DNS server's machine.
2. I started the Windows DNS Server on that machine
3. Set a Forward Lookup Zone of lan.[ourdomain].com
4. Set two A records, one for wiki, one for pgadmin
5. I set Google's public DNS to be the forwarders for the Windows DNS
6. In dd-wrt, I set the DNS server's local ip to be the number one
   static DNS
7. I also set "Local DNS" in the Network Setup pane to be the local ip
   of the DNS server

What else should I be setting?  Like I said, I'm trying to just have the router point at my local DNS server to resolve names, and then I'll have the DNS server forward unresolvable requests.  I don't want to use Dnsmasq because I don't want to be managing DNS records on my router.  Is this possible?

Here's a screenshot of the settings:

[image: Screenshot of my dd-wrt settings]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have the windows DNS server do the forwarding.  Point everything, including the router, solely at the windows dns server for DNS.

Systems dont always use their dns servers in a specific order, so having both your internal and some public resolvers in there causes problems.  Only your windows dns server should talk to outside dns servers.

Comment: Awesome, I'll give it a go and see what happens.

Comment: @zaemz Be sure to reconfigure any dhcp servers to give out the windows server for dns.